# WCF service calls service

Tags: wcf, service, timeout, client, synchronous

I have two .net 3.5 WCF services where service A calls service B synchronously.

Both services are on the same machine and with this behavior:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

I created the client for service B and use it like this inside a `OperationContract` of service A:

```
Proxyclient client = null;
bool error = true;
int returnVal = 0;

try
{
  client = new Proxyclient;
  returnVal = client.CallServiceB();
  client.Close();
  error = false;
}
finally
{
  if (error)
  {
    client.Abort();
  }
}
```

But when service A will be called it writes an error into TraceListener logfile:

> There was an error writing to the pipe unrecognized error 232.

Please note this message is binding specific (`netNamedPipeBinding`). For all other bindings I tested I got an error too. The general meaning for other bindings would be:

> Could not write / connect the connection timed out and has been
>   closed.

However, the service / client works, it just produces the error in logfile so I think WCF works on retry base here. But this spams my logfiles and I am not sure if that would make some problems in the future.

Some very special thing to note:

This problem only occurs when client had not called service B for more than 2 minutes (but this time changes for each binding I tested). So on first time after service start there is no error in log and if I would call this service every 10 seconds there would be also no error in log.

What i have done yet:

1. I played with the timeout settings for all services without any changes
2. I put the client into an Console App and called Service B from that console app. Here it does not write these errors !
3. I tested this on multiple machines and got the problem on all of them.
4. I removed ALL CODE from Service A and B. I just had the WCF basic code and still had this problem.

I hope someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.